# Variable assignment in numpy not working?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just starting to learn how to code, so this may seem like a stupid question, but I'm trying to build a simple program where the computer generates a random number and the user has 1 chance to get it right.

However, the program always gets stuck on this variable:

`number = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=1)`

I don't know if this function can't be put as a variable (it works by itself, but not when assigned to "number"), but whenever I run it this appears:

````
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/Python/App.py", line 4, in <module>
    print("The number was " + number)
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. Firstly `number` is not an int but a Numpy array containing an int. If you just omit the `size` argument it will give you an int.

```
number = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10)
```

Secondly you're trying to add a string with a Numpy array, which won't work. Same for adding a string and an int (`TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`). So instead of adding, put `number` as a separate argument to `print` and it will automatically get converted to a string and separated by a space.

```
print("The number was", number)
```

Also, Numpy is overkill here when you could use the `random` module from the standard library. Confusingly, `np.random.randint` seems to be equivalent to `random.randrange`, not `random.randint`.

```
import random
number = random.randrange(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate a string with a `numpy ndarray`
You need to convert number to string.

```
>>> number = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=1)
>>>
>>> print("test " + number)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11') dtype('<U11')
>>>
>>> print("test" + str(number))
test[8]
```